# Video Streaming over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi I want to stream a video from my android phone to another android phone over bluetooth, I see that there is a VDP to use but this profile is not available in android sdk there is a profile A2dp which is responsible for audio streaming only. Is there a different method in order to implement that with android sdk?

Comment: Do you have any solution for this problem??? Please :( @jikes

Comment: i solved it at the end the problem is that android is not supporting broacast after the version 4.1.2 so you cannot use the rtp protocol you should use the RFCOMM channels so first you pair the devices (you need two threads for that) and after that you make the stream (here you are using another thread which is managing the connection you create before) using the camera preview frame method which taking images from the phone camera  converting those images to byteArray only that can be read from bluetooth output stream. The display of the video you should do it through image view.

Comment: Thanks @jikes You save my life! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As I known, if you want to make the video streaming over bluetooth, it's not suitable. Because whether SPP or BLE is not suitable for this kind of mass data transmission, I mean that if you want to make it as good as the A2DP over bluetooth, I mean the Real-Time. But if you don't care about the Real-Time. You can use SPP or BLE to transmit the video data, and encode/decode the video data by yourself. The most important is that the transmit speed of Bluetooth.

If you just only need to transmit the video file to the other device, you can treat the video as a file, and transmit it as data.

Comment: i want to create an app that will transmit live video between two devices  over bluetooth the problem is that android is not supporting VDP i have find something about SPP but i don't know if it's going to work you have any source code examples of SPP and BLE ?

Comment: maybe  i will use L2CAP protocol and RFCOMM sockets but i am not sure

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an AVDTP profile to do that in Bluetooth classic.
and even AVCTP for controlling that stream as well.